# Xcode 7 beta 6 stuck on "copying Pkginfo"

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2, xcode7-beta6

When I try to install app on my iPhone the Xcode gets stuck on **Copying Pkginfo**.

I have deleted Xcode beta & installed it again. Still same problem.

I created new single page app & not a single line of code. It works on simulator but does not install on my iPhone 5s with iOS 9 beta 5 installed in it.

None of the apps are getting installed on iPhone from Xcode.

It was working fine & suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Have you tried anothe iPhone? it might be a problem with your phone. You could restore it and try again

Comment: sorry I only own 1 iPhone

Comment: Try to reset it then and see what is happening

Comment: You were right problem was in iPhone. I restarted my iPhone again & again until suddenly everything started to work. Do you want to write answer? I will accept it.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Xcode 12 and iOS 14. I've restarted my iPhone and Mac more times than I can remember but it still hangs every time. Any more ideas?

Comment: @AdamSwinden have you tried resetting the phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with betas is a little bit hard and sometimes strange things happen, like this one.

When something suddenly stops working you should try a **restart** for your Mac and for your IPhone especially when it works on simulator but on phone not.

This must be your first solution when things like this happen.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to run an iOS app from the command line (in Android Studio using KMM to be precise) **while the app was still running in XCode**. Just closing XCode solved the issue - there were problems with two process trying to simultaneously access my iPad.